# Why am I getting this bundler error in an existing project that uses Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

This error happens during just about any rake task:

```
project/Gemfile:4:in `evaluate': undefined method `ruby' for #<Bundler::Dsl:0x007f8274ba6ac8> (NoMethodError)
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-perf/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `instance_eval'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-perf/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `evaluate'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-perf/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:18:in `build'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-perf/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:135:in `definition'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-perf/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-perf/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0-perf/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
```

**Gemfile:4**

```
  ruby '1.9.3'
```

Comment: I googled for the error with no luck and a co-worker pointed me to the post below that they had used.  Hopefully this entry will make it easier for people to diagnose a similar error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This line is required for running multiple versions of ruby on Heroku, but currently requires a prerelease version of bundler to work locally.

```
gem install bundler --pre
```

See http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/9/multiple_ruby_version_support_on_heroku/

Comment: it is now in release version bigger than 1.2.  if you need 1.1, there is a version 1.1.5 that ignores it instead if throwing an error.